# Angular : How to load background image(without line-to-line loading) before "container"?

Tags: css, angularjs

How do you load background image without it being loaded line to line before the login container loads? Because right now, the container appears first before the background image is loaded. I want to load the image first before the container is loaded. I have tried inserting my own directive but it doesn't work for me.

This is my controller:

```
    app.controller('loginctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {


    }]);
MainApp.directive('imageonload', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('load', function () {
                return true;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This is my css:

```
body {
    background: url("someurl");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This is my html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    </head>
    <body ng-app="app">
        <div ng-controller="loginctrl">
            <img ng-src="{{imageSrc}}" imageonload >
            <div id="container container-table">
                <div class="login">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                        <div id="loginModel">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">


                                        <p>{{message}}</p>

                                    </div>


                                    <div class="modal-body" ng-init="getURL('@Model.URL')">

                                        <form style="padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;">
                                            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': userForm.username.$invalid }">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" ng-model="username" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': userForm.password.$invalid }">
                                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" />
                                            </div>

                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <div>
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right " ng-click="login()">Log In</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This article might have some useful suggestions for you: [preloading-images-in-angularjs-with-promises](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2597-reloading-images-in-angularjs-with-promises.htm)